# Exception while using SiteEdit with a Page Template in Template Builder

Tags: tridion

I am trying to enable SiteEdit on our Tridion 2011 SP1.

I have installed and configured SiteEdit.

I tried adding SiteEdit for a page through Template Builder by following the below steps and got the below exception.

1. Created a page with two components
2. In the page template I added the "Enable SiteEdit 2009" TBB below Dreamweaver template
3. Added the Target type URI in the parameter TargetTypeURI of the parameter schema field.
4. when  executed it is throwing the below exception.

> Debugging was started in process 'TcmTemplateDebugHost' with id 2464
>   Invalid item type. A page template, component template or template building block was expected.
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.GetTemplate(TcmUri templateURI)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className)
>      at Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine __engine, Package __package)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template template, Package package)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggingEngine.Run()
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebugSession.Run()

Comment: Can you describe how you installed the "Enable SiteEdit 2009" TBB, because it looks like something went wrong there.

Comment: The Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.SiteEdit.dll was uploaded in another publication using TCMUploadAssembly and i faced issue(exception : "Error: PDB uploading is selected, but could not find PDB file")  while uploading the same assembly.So i copied the tbbcs files from other publication and pasted in my publication using webdav. I have all the parameter schema required.

Comment: You don't have the PDB for this assembly, so you should not specify /uploadpdb:true on the command line. Aside from that, uploading this DLL should be no different from any others you may have created yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps for installing the Template Building Blocks are documented [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SiteEdit_2009_SP3/task_InstSETBB85D8DE69746A49BDBD57742DB2FF46FC). It looks like you made a mistake either in step 2 when uploading the assembly or in step 7 when installing `Enable SiteEdit 2009.tbbcs`.

### Create the C# fragment for Enabling SiteEdit 2009

In this 7 step you must paste this code into a new C# TBB:

```
<%RunTemplate Template="tcm:0-0-0"
        Class="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.EnableSiteEdit"%>
```

And then change the value of the `Template` attribute to match with the TCM URI of the Assembly you created in step 2. So it will look something like:

```
<%RunTemplate Template="tcm:1-479-2048"
        Class="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Templates.EnableSiteEdit"%>
```

The first two numbers (1 and 479 above) will very likely be different on your system. But the last number will always be 2048. It looks like you may have gotten the URI wrong and you have it ending in `-2464`.

Double check the TCM URI of your Assembly TBB against the one in the `Template` attribute and make sure they match.

### Upload the Assembly

If you find yourself stuck figuring out `TcmUploadAssembly`, you can also choose to create upload the DLL into Tridion from the web GUI. Simply create a new TBB, set the language to Assembly and choose `Load from disk`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Solved my problem by following you instruction.

Comment: Sorry to ask this basic question.. I am first time implementing the siteEdit. Now i am done with uploading the dll , parameter schema,.
. How to configure the Publication target(where i have to publish the page so that i can see the site edit toolbar(configuring the webserver and linking the publishing from content manager).

I am little confused at this stage. I added the site edit tbb and published the page. It got published to staging server(not the machine where the siteEdit is installed).When i opened the page in IE i am not able to see the siteEdit link to edit the content.
Please help.

Comment: You publish your page with SiteEdit commands (the <!-- Start SiteEdit... comments) to your regular staging server, that is normal. You then access those pages through the SiteEdit proxy server, which will reach out to your staging server. Doing this allows SiteEdit to avoid cross-origin problems. I typically find this diagram in the documentation quite helpful: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SiteEdit_2009_SP3/concept_21A5264A1CA14110BCFE42750ACD5057

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to access the staging website through the SiteEdit Proxy. Can you please give me some pointer or how to do it.

Comment: When you installed SiteEdit, you told it which site to create on the server. If you didn't change anything, it will have create a website on port 84 binding to all available IP addresses. So in that case you can access the site by going to http://your-cm-server-name:84/. SiteEdit will then request the root of the staging web site you configured during installation.

Comment: Hi
I have published the page after adding the Enable Inline Editing in compoennt Template and Enable SiteEdit 2009 in Page page Template.

I am able to access through the proxy as you mentioned. I am able to see the page as well but when i try to edit none of the field are editable. 
Is there anything specific i have to check. I am able to see the Site Edit Toolbar in the Browser and the component also got initialized. 
Please help.

Comment: This is now the third problem you pose on one StackOverflow question that is unrelated to programming. Although I'll gladly help anyone, this type of support is not very well suited for Stack Overflow. You might want to consider openening a customer support ticket or reaching out to your Tridion account manager in some way to get help from our professional services. That said: check if your published HTML contains the necessary SiteEdit commands that are documented here: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SiteEdit_2009_SP3/concept_SECLRef1247BCB0533849F2B3BBD6ADD51AD9B0